# How to build hsdis.dll for Windows 32-bit?

Tags: dll, cygwin

I am trying to build hsdis.dll in my laptop 32-bit Windows. I read http://dropzone.nfshost.com/hsdis.htm instructions and got to know that  I will have to follow those steps. I saw that I have to use the mingw64-i686-gcc-core. I followed the steps, but have always  found this error.

```
make[2]: i686-w64-mingw32: Command not found
Makefile:246: recipe for target 'libiberty.a' failed
make[2]: *** [libiberty.a] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/User/hsdis/build/Linux-i586/libiberty'
Makefile:8045: recipe for target 'all-libiberty' failed
make[1]: *** [all-libiberty] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/User/hsdis/build/Linux-i586'
Makefile:192: recipe for target 'build/Linux-i586/bfd/libbfd.a' failed
make: *** [build/Linux-i586/bfd/libbfd.a] Error 2
```

I would also like to know how to use the directive PrintAssembly, because i wanted to see the assembly code, of a Java class.

I have already saw other posts here, but none of them helped.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also failed to build 64-bit version on my laptop.

Comment: what kind of error did you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which help me to build it (x64 version, x86 should be almost the same):

- download and unpack the latest `hsdis` sources as described in the building manual from the http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/tags;
- download the latest `bintuils-2.26.tar.gz` package from the http://mirror.tochlab.net/pub/gnu/binutils/;
- copy it to your Cygwin home directory and unpack it from the Cygwin terminal (this is very important, otherwise you may get permission problems):
  `tar -xzvf ./binutils-2.26.tar.gz`
- install the following Cygwin packages: `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` for x64 or `mingw64-i686-gcc-core` for x86, `diffutils` and `make`;
- go to `hsdis` directory;
- for x64 library build with the command: `make OS=Linux MINGW=x86_64-w64-mingw32 'AR=x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar' BINUTILS=~/binutils-2.26 CONFIGURE_ARGS="--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32"`, for x86 library build with the command: `make OS=Linux MINGW=i686-w64-mingw32 'AR=i686-w64-mingw32-ar' BINUTILS=~/binutils-2.26 CONFIGURE_ARGS="--host=i686-w64-mingw32"`
- if you have errors with undefined references to `zlib` (i.e. `build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to inflate`), modify `Makefile` in `hsdis`: find the line `$(CC) $(OUTFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCE) $(DLDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES)` for the `$(TARGET)` target and append to the end `-lz -L$(TARGET_DIR)/zlib`, then run the build command again;
- after that you should find the library `hsdis-amd64.dll` in `hsdis\build\Linux-amd64\` for x64, or `hsdis-i386.dll` in `hsdis\build\Linux-i586\` for x86.

Comment: Your point before the last, about appending `-lz -L$(TARGET_DIR)/zlib`, doesn't seem to work. I get the same error. The full output is here http://pastebin.com/RdzPVs9z

Comment: @leventov How did you unpack `binutils` package? It seems that your binutils-2.26 directory misses some files according to this: `gcc.exe: error: /home/leventov/binutils-2.26/bfd/doc/chew.c: No such file or directory`. This may happen if you unpack archive under Windows directly, not under the Cygwin terminal. Original `binutils` archive must have this file. Also check that your `binutils` has downloaded correctly.

Comment: I unpacked binutils using 7-Zip FM.

Comment: @leventov I also had the similar problem when tried to use 7-Zip FM. Try to download a .tar.gz version of `binutils` archive and unpack it under the Cygwin shell as I have described in Step 3.

Comment: `chew.c` is present, and visible from cygwin terminal. (after unpacking with `tar`). But gcc mysteriously doesn't see it.

Comment: You may have to pick the devel/"gcc-core" as well when installing Cygwin (also run setup again and modify the packages) and remove the hsdis build directory entirely when retrying. Then you might need to do the zlib again.